# How to join files using string contains function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames that look like this:

df1

```
cleaned_transaction_data
MR PRICE FNB WHK
NANDOS
MR PRICE
CHECKERS WERNH
PICK'N PAY FNB
EAT-SUM-MOR-MEAT LUDERI
SPAR SWAKOPMUND FNB
LEGIT SWAKOP
SHOPRITE
KFC
```

df2

```
merchant_name        description_merchant
CHECKERS             groceries
MR PRICE             clothing
EAT-SUM-MOR-MEAT     butchery
PICK PAY             groceries            
LEGIT                clothing
SPAR                 supermarket
```

I would like to merge these data frames using the string contains function in python, if df1.cleaned_transaction_data contains a similar string in df2.merchant_name then output df2.description_merchant.

I tried using the code below but it only returns 1 output, this is because the names in the dataframes are not exactly same hence the reason i would like to use the contain function.

Python Code:

```
dfnew = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on= 'cleaned_transaction_data', right_on='merchant_name')
```

This is the output i got from the code i used:

```
cleaned_transaction_data        merchant_name        description_merchant
  MR PRICE                        MR PRICE              clothing
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
cleaned_transaction_data        merchant_name        description_merchant
  MR PRICE FNB WHK                MR PRICE              clothing
  NANDOS                           null                   null
  MR PRICE                         MR PRICE             clothing
  CHECKERS WERNH                  CHECKERS              groceries
  PICK'N PAY FNB                  PICK PAY              groceries
  EAT-SUM-MOR-MEAT LUDERI        EAT-SUM-MOR-MEAT       butchery
  SHOPRITE                        null                    null
  LEGIT SWAKOP                   LEGIT                  clothing
  KFC                              null                   null
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get first values from `df2['merchant_name']` joined by `|` for regex `OR` and `\b\b` for words boundaries, for second column use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in df2['merchant_name'])

df1['merchant_name'] = df1['cleaned_transaction_data'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')',expand=False)
s = df2.set_index('merchant_name')['description_merchant']
df1['description_merchant'] = df1['merchant_name'].map(s)

print (df1)
  cleaned_transaction_data     merchant_name description_merchant
0         MR PRICE FNB WHK          MR PRICE             clothing
1                   NANDOS               NaN                  NaN
2                 MR PRICE          MR PRICE             clothing
3           CHECKERS WERNH          CHECKERS            groceries
4           PICK'N PAY FNB               NaN                  NaN
5  EAT-SUM-MOR-MEAT LUDERI  EAT-SUM-MOR-MEAT             butchery
6      SPAR SWAKOPMUND FNB              SPAR          supermarket
7             LEGIT SWAKOP             LEGIT             clothing
8                 SHOPRITE               NaN                  NaN
9                      KFC               NaN                  NaN
```